# Raspberry pi 4 and Viewsonic monitor with touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen, raspbian-buster

The question is: does monitor "MONITOR VIEWSONIC 21,5" LED LCD TOUCH TD2220 VGA/DVI" support touchscreen on raspberry pi 4? If you have any prior experiences or educated guesses then please help. I have been googling around. There were some confirmations on the topic but not enough for a bigger buy. As far for contacting the vendor there is stil no respone.
I would appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: The important part of the monitor spec is the "USB HID Touch driver", which is supported in Linux, though the multi-touch may not be supported as well as in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Viewsonic TD2220** works perfectly via USB as a touch screen with `1920x1080`. [*Source*](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=315322#p315322)

Write the last Raspbian Buster to your SD-Card and plug the USB cable to the Raspberry Pi, it's also hot-swapped/hot-plugged.

Comment: @IvanŽ If you install ubuntu or another operating system instead of the raspbian buster, you may need to add some drivers.

Comment: Thank you so much. Wasn't sure my question was on spot so i just deleted it.

Comment: @IvanŽ My pleasure, no problem.

Comment: Additonal confirmation sources are still welcome from anyone for anyone in the future too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what they wrote in the Overview section (https://www.viewsonic.com/eu/products/lcd/TD1630-3):

> The ViewSonic TD1630-3 is a 16” (15.6” viewable) display with 10-point multi-touch functionality. With an advanced ergonomic design, the TD1630-3 can tilt or lay flat to give users maximum comfort. Delivering touchscreen versatility, this display offers fantastic flexibility for retail or business settings, while VGA and HDMI inputs provide ample connectivity. Compatibility with a wide range of operating systems, including Windows 10 and Linux versions*, along with dual integrated speakers, make this intuitive touchscreen a highly accurate, ultra-responsive touch experience that is ideal for interactivity in a retail or business settings.
> *Supports Windows 7/8/10, Linux Kernel 4.X/3.X

This *seems* as a newer product so it probably supports all versions. We use RPi version 2, 3 and 4 and the touchscreen and display works fine. I dont think it supports multi point touch. For a final confirmatio  write to them directly.

Good luck.

Comment: ave you read the link and the text you quote? *with 10-point multi-touch functionality*

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Im quite sure there was someone with another question in this post.... If I could i would delete this comment / answer since its my post and peopel already helped me.